# Error con read_csv(): 'charmap' codec can't decode byte #### in position ####: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, encoding

Intento leer un archivo csv utilizando Pandas y recibo este error porque tiene líneas con esta clase de caracteres:  ªå¼ä¼šç¤¾ã‹ã‚‰ç·Šæ€¥ã®ã”é€£çµ¡ãƒ¡

Ya intenté:

- Todos y cada uno de los encoding de esta página:
  https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/codecs.html y de esta otra:
  https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html
- Crear una función para reconocer el encoding usando chardet
- Cambiar el encoding del archivo
- Eliminar el parámetro encoding
- Incluir el parámetro encoding_errors='ignore', 'replace' y demás
  variaciones
- Incluir el parámetro on_bad_lines='skip' y error_bad_lines=False

Eliminar manualmente las líneas del archivo antes de procesarlo no es una opción.

Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: Decirle a pandas que abra el archivo con encoding="utf-8" me funciona perfecto con los caracteres de muestra. Si eso no funciona (probablemente ya que parece que lo intentaste) Podrías agregar un csv de muestra donde ocurra el fallo por favor? Por cierto, gracias por demostrarnos tu esfuerzo c:

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Otra pregunta, el bloc de notas lo abre sin ningún problema no?

Comment: Igual, todo lo intentado debería de funcionar. Por lo que mi pregunta termina siendo... Revisaste que el código que estás ejecutando sea el mismo que el que estás editando?

Comment: @DanteS. utf-8 es el que uso comúnmente y con el primero que intenté. Y sí, de hecho el block de notas indica que es ANSI y lo modifiqué a utf-8 y aún así el problema persiste cuando pruebo mi programa. Cabe aclarar que intenté con otros archivos que son extracciones del que debería usar y funciona perfectamente e inserté varios print() para detectar el problema y se imprimieron por la consola. Por lo tanto es el mismo archivo el que modifico y el que corro

Comment: Descartando fallos durante el guardado del código y el encoding entonces... Sobre que las extracciones funcionan, entonces debe de haber un caracter conflictivo que no está entre los que muestras ni en las extracciones del csv. Generalmente, el error indica en que byte ocurrió el fallo. Podrías agregar el mensaje de error por favor?

Comment: Hice un pequeño código que obtiene el error que se produce al leer un archivo y determina la linea y columna con el error (cuidado, carga en memoria todo el archivo antes del caracter erroneo): https://pastebin.com/kTGER0Vx

Comment: @DanteS. tiene la misma estructura que la función alternativa que hice para abrirlo, pero hago line.decode("utf-8", "ignore")... de todas formas el error salta en open c':

Comment: Que raro. open no lee el archivo, recien cuando lees el archivo debería de dar error. Podrías agregar el mensaje de error, algún código de muestra por favor?

Comment: Hola Tatiana, bienvenida, creo que deberías mostrarnos tu código, para poder ayudarte, con más fundamento, te sugiero que hagas el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0):

En ambas tablas de los links no está el siguiente encoding:

```py
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('archivo_plano.csv', encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
```

Prueba.